# Cordova SQLite plugin - UPDATE statement not always successful - guidance needed

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

We have a database table that has a column called `image1` - this contains a base 64 string of an image. We then upload the string to a third-party service which creates an image and passes back a URL. We then update `image1` with the URL.

This seems to work about 70% of the time, but so far I've not been able to account for the times that the column is not updated. This is the function I wrote:

```
updatePhotoURL(dbid, photoUrl) {
    console.group("### updatePhotoURL() called, dbid, photoUrl:", dbid, photoUrl);

    let sqlQuery = 'UPDATE table SET image1=? WHERE dbid=?'

    return new Observable<object>((obs) => {
      this.openDatabase()
        .flatMap((db) => {
          return Observable.fromPromise(db.executeSql(sqlQuery, [photoUrl, dbid]))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.info("### error")
          console.table(error)

          let extra = `dbid: ${dbid == undefined ? 'undefined' : dbid}, `

          if (photoUrl == undefined) {
            extra += `photoUrl: undefined`
          } else {
            extra += `photoUrl: ${photoUrl.length > 0 ? photoUrl.substr(0, 20) + "..." : ""}`
          }

          obs.error({ r: "updatePhotoURL() catch()", s: error.code, m: error.message, e: extra })
          obs.complete()

          return error;
        })
        .map((dbUpdate) => {
          if (dbUpdate.rowsAffected == 0) {

            let extra = `dbid: ${dbid == undefined ? 'undefined' : dbid},`

            if (photoUrl == undefined) {
              extra += `photoUrl: undefined`
            } else {
              extra += `photoUrl: ${photoUrl.length > 0 ? photoUrl.substr(0, 20) + "..." : ""}`
            }

            obs.error({ r: "updatePhotoURL() function", s: 0, m: 'Could not update photo URL for this snag in storage', e: extra })

          } else {
            obs.next(dbUpdate)
          }

          obs.complete()

          return dbUpdate
        })
        .subscribe((success) => {

          console.groupEnd()

        });
    });
  }
```

As I said earlier, this works a lot of the time, but occasionally we're seeing the database is not updating, and I don't understand why. I've added a `catch()` to the SQL statement execution so if there is any sort of error then we're catching it, but I never seem to get anything from this. After that I've got a `map()` function which checks to see if the value of `rowsAffected` equals 0 - so if for some reason we're not seeing an error when executing the SQL statement, then we trigger an error because the database row wasn't affected. I am able to trigger the `map()` function but it doesn't help me get to the root cause.

I can confirm that the `dbid` of the row does exist, and the value of `photoUrl` is definitely a string URL. Is there anything else generally that I can check or should look out for?

Thanks,
bengrah

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to pinpoint the exact reason why the column is not being updated without more information about the error messages or any specific logs that you might have. However, here are a few possible scenarios that might help you troubleshoot the issue:

Third-party service error: If the third-party service that creates the image and returns the URL is experiencing issues or is down, the column may not be updated. In this case, you could try logging the response from the third-party service to check if there are any errors or if the URL is being returned correctly.

Database connection issue: It's possible that the database connection is failing, which could result in the column not being updated. You could try logging any errors related to the database connection to check if this is the case.

Invalid or incomplete base 64 string: If the base 64 string in the image1 column is invalid or incomplete, the third-party service may not be able to create an image and return a URL. In this case, you could try logging the base 64 string to check if it's valid and complete.

Incorrect SQL query: If the SQL query is incorrect, it could result in the column not being updated. You could try logging the SQL query to check if it's correct and matches the table structure.

I would suggest adding more logging and error handling to the function to help identify the root cause of the issue. Additionally, you could try testing the function with different base 64 strings and URLs to see if the issue is consistent or intermittent.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).